# SqlExpress using %appdata%

Tags: sql-server-express, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC 5 and the default authentication built in using the Live\Microsoft sign on.

It appears that the site is firing up SQLExpress targeting a folder in %appdata% as the directory.

Here is my connection string:
    Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

Why wouldn't it just use the instance of SQLExpress that is already running. For whatever reason I can't connect sql studio to this private instance of sqlexpress which makes it rather frustrating.

How do I get it to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. The "User Instance=True" part of the connection string was doing it.